# Enable to call function to return another value

Tags: php, arrays

Why this code do not return me the right text please ?

```
// My function
function getActivitiesDatas($datas, $got, $to_find) {
    foreach ($datas as $d) {
        if (array_search($got, $d)) {
            if (in_array($to_find, array_keys($d))) {
                return trim($d[$to_find]);
            }
        }
    }
}

// My array
$activitiesList = array(
    array(
        'dbTable'         =>   "Outfitters", 
        'dbPrefix'        =>   "OUT",
        'fullName'        =>   "F_ACTIVITY0001",
        'rewriteName'     =>   $R_ACTIVITY0001,
        'sectionType'     =>   "accommodation",
        'activeSeasons'   =>   "all",
        'weatherDep'      =>   "no"
    )
);

// My function call
$R_ACTIVITY0001 = "outfitters";
echo getActivitiesDatas($activitiesList, "OUT", "rewriteName");
```

My problem is the following: when I call my function the `$rewriteName`, is blank when I try to return the `rewriteName` parameters from my array.

When, in my array I try to replace the value `$R_ACTIVITY0001` by `"R_ACTIVITY0001"`, it works.

Why ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the order, you need to initialize $R_ACTIVITY0001 before initialize your array like this:

```
$R_ACTIVITY0001 = "outfitters";

$activitiesList = array(
    array(
        'dbTable'         =>   "Outfitters", 
        'dbPrefix'        =>   "OUT",
        'fullName'        =>   "F_ACTIVITY0001",
        'rewriteName'     =>   $R_ACTIVITY0001,
        'sectionType'     =>   "accommodation",
        'activeSeasons'   =>   "all",
        'weatherDep'      =>   "no"
    )
);
```

Comment: Thanks. You was the first.

Answer (score 0):

```
$R_ACTIVITY0001 = "outfitters";

$activitiesList = array(
    array(
        'dbTable'         =>   "Outfitters", 
        'dbPrefix'        =>   "OUT",
        'fullName'        =>   "F_ACTIVITY0001",
        'rewriteName'     =>   $R_ACTIVITY0001,
        'sectionType'     =>   "accommodation",
        'activeSeasons'   =>   "all",
        'weatherDep'      =>   "no"
    )
);
```

Your variable is not initialize before your array